# Extract XML data from URL with authentication into a SQL table

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

I have been battling extracting data from the URL that requires me to authenticate, pass the page size, then pull the cursor from the results returned i.e Cursor is at the last row on the page, then pass the next page size until the cursor not found. The end of all results doesn't have a cursor, which means is where I will stop passing the URL with a page size and a cursor.

I have used SSIS `web task`, but that only passes the URL once and get the result set for the only one page size. E.g 10 rows for the page_size=10. I have tried using C#, but not much knowledgeable on C#. Can somebody please help.

E.g. `https://{mydomain}.com/dev/api/opportunity?page_size=10`

at the 10th record I will have a cursor, then have to pass it on to the URL like:

`https:{domain}.com/dev/api/opportunity?page_size=10&cursor=ABC123xyz`
which means next 10 records. Do the same until the cursor is not found at the bottom xml row.

Comment: Hi this question is very vague and lacks a lot of the details needed to answer this question. Please read the [help], specifically [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Liam, not sure how you did not understand the question: I have data to extract from the web url, which returns xml data. SO, first set of results are dependent on the page size that I provide, I cannot pass a big number to pass all the pages, it times out, so I have to do it in batches of pages specified on url. At the end of the XML page there's has a cursor name returned on this xml results. I then have to use that cursor to pass it onto the URL+page size in-order to get result set 2, until when the cursor name not found, which will define end of the records. Is my question better now?

Comment: You need to Navigate to each page to get all the data.  Usually I like to use two browsers.  One for the main webpage and the 2nd to naviage through all the pages.  This way I have the original webpage in case there is different data in the main page than the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This came in very helpful, and it worked in my case.

http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.co.za/2013/05/using-script-component-source-to.html